# Failure email becomes unformatted

Tags: asp.net, email, formatting

I am sending email using asp.net and it is working fine. But when an email gets failure to deliver then the failure email which i get becomes unformatted.

the email contents are in html format and attached .doc files.
i am smtp for sending emails.

i think that, this is not because of code i am using to send email so i am not putting sending code here.

Please suggest me what should i check.

Thanks

Comment: Failure emails are usually plain text... I don't think that you are able to change that. The failure email will be sent from your mailsystem and not within your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail failure of mail sending is because of your smtp configuration or by data transportation blockage. and this will read your attachment as byte[] so its only the reason to make sure that your smtp configuration is well working...

Comment: i am not asking why email got failure.. i asked that why my email gets unformatted, when it delivered to me back for email failure.

Comment: I think when stmp send's a mail this uses http protocols so the data will be in byte array and by any reasion data was unable to sent the form of data will be get back to its sender that's why we got the unformated data back.